# I can't create a NTFS partition in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, ntfs

When I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04, I try to create a NTFS partition but I can't find it. There are FAT16, FAT32, ext... but not NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

Since, You are in the installation process, I suggest you to boot into the Live Session, (Try Ubuntu).

Then press <kbd>Super</kbd> button to bring dash and type "gparted". After opening it, create NTFS partition using that tool.

Note, You don't need to install gparted in Live CD/USB. Gparted is already included in the Live session.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "**GParted**"

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

and check your partitions, you can also create the NTFS partition.

Answer (score -1):

We install Ubuntu on `ext` filesystems. You may make following partitions:

Partition 1
Ext3 or Ext4
mount point = "/"

Partition 2 (4GB?)
Use as: swap

Installation should work fine.

Comment: yeah i know . But I need to have windows in a partition (i need it for many programs)

Comment: Did he say that he wanted to install Ubuntu in NTFS?