# How to format a filesystem hdd(not partition) from ext4 to ntfs

Tags: filesystem, ssd, ntfs, format, ext4

I have ubuntu 18.04 in my laptop. As it was my 1st laptop I bought it without OS in order to install only ubuntu. But now I want to put windows 10 on it. And I have this specific problem. 1st of all I can't resize or make any partition cause I have only an SSD which I made him ext4 from the beginning in order to put Ubuntu.2nd I tried from "disks" to format the SSD but when you are logged in as it was expected you cant format the disk. Also i cant format it or resize it from Gparted cause it is locked(it has a key at the right side of the drive's name). So my question is this how I can format my ubuntu filesystem SSD from ext4 to Ntfs. I have made my backups but how on earth do i make this happen? The only answers im seeing is by making a partition but what happens when i can not?

Comment: In order to change a partition size, you must `umount` it (ie stop using it).  By far the easiest way to do that is to boot a 'live' system and use it that way.  *there are file-systems that allow on-the-fly resizing but my statement ignores those as it just complicates your issue*

Comment: Do you want to remove Ubuntu and install Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't create a NTFS partition in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191957/i-cant-create-a-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu) Even if HDD is to be formatted to NTFS, it would still comprise of a partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always resize or format your partition except when you are using it / have it mounted.

So to resize or format the root partition you have to use an ubuntu installation media like an usb stick and boot from that. This way the root partition is not in use. Run from there gparted and resize or reformat your partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize or format your partition to any file system but you have to change your sata configuration to acpi in bios settings. After that run gparted live cd and thats it.